# jQuery mmenu: Position of menu next to the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

As far as I tested the jQuery.mmenu I can descide wheter I want to have the menu left or right in the browser window.

The design of my website does not take 100% of the screen, so I would like to position the menu at the top left of the design and **not** top left of the browser window.

The Javascript of the jQuery.mmenu moves the html of the menu directly after the opening body tag, so it is not in the html structure of the design anymore. Pure CSS positioning does not help I guess :-(

```html
<!-- The page -->
<div class="page">

   <!-- The menu -->
   <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

   <div class="header">
      <a href="#menu">Open mmenu</a><br>
      Demo
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <p><strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
         Click the menu icon to open the menu.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the menu is inside the div ".page", but the Javascript of the mmenu moves it outside. See http://jsfiddle.net/qncfkjbg/
I would like to open the menu at the top left of the yellow area and not at the top left of the window.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
top:10px;
left:10px;
```

apply this css you can change the top and left respectively

Comment: Hm, as far as I know the Javascript of the mmenu copies the menu-code right ofter the body-tag, so it is outsied of the html structure of my design. So with position:fixed I can't have the menu directly at the top left of my design (I don't want to have it top left of the browser window)

Comment: can you put your code on fiddle so that I can help you in detail

Comment: Please find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qncfkjbg/ I would like to open the menu at the top left of the yellow area and not at the top left of the window. Appreciate your help!

Comment: In mmenu.js file they are adding explicitly that menu at left top of body we can change in mmenu.js so that it will display in yellow where you want but changing in mmenu.js file will effect in other pages as well so do you want it in that way